# Why is the Google Maps Places Autocomplete API so uncommon in signup forms, but so common in search?

Tags: input-fields, maps, google, autocomplete, addresses

When looking at signup forms, the standard is always to break it down in address, house number, city, zip code, country; all in separate input fields for the user. But when you look at search on Airbnb, Maps, Uber etc. it is so common to use the Google Maps Places Autocomplete API...

Why is it that signup forms do not utilize the same API & ask the user for only one input instead of 5+ separate input fields? Especially on mobile it provides an easier interaction in my opinion.

What are the downsides of the autocomplete single field address that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data privacy: you don't want for every registration on your website for user address to be send to Google. With search it doesn't really matter.

This might be also because of database normalization - see [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

I personally hate forms that have more than *Address line* field on website. And especially the ones with predefined list of streets assigned to street postcode. Please, try to enter *Poste restante* or *P. O. Box* or *Packstation* into one of them.